# as.date not working in R script for Jupyter Books

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have been writing code in R studio and tried to move it over to Jupyer Books to share it with people.

The code all works in R studio but when I run it in Jupyer Books, as.date() does not convert the date column which begins as a factor into a date which then means I have no data when I subset by date later on.

Has anyone had this happen and know a solution? Or will I just need to use lubridate or similar to convert the date?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are running different R versions in both places. Run `R.version.string` at both the places to check which version of R you are running at each of them. Since R 4.0.0 the default behaviour of R changed when importing string data into R. Previously they were imported as factors and now (since 4.0.0) they are imported as characters.

The solution is to import your dataset with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in both the places to see the same output at both the places.

```
data <- read.csv('filename.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```